# How to only import part of an Angular library?

Tags: angular, angular-library

**My goal:**

1. To only import part of an Angular library.

Let say I have `MyAppUI` library which have 2 NgModules:

1. MyAppButtonModule
2. MyAppCheckboxModule

Then I have a `/app3/view1` path which import `MyAppButtonModule`.

**My expected result:**

1. when I visit `/app3/view1`, the browser will only download `MyAppButtonModule`.

**My actual result:**

1. when I vist the page, in `common.js`, I see that `MyAppCheckboxModule` is also present.

The solution (which is not desirable):

1. import to projects instead of `@@myAppUI`:

   1. `import { MyAppButtonModule } from 'projects/my-app-ui/src/lib/my-app-button/my-app-button.module'`
   2. `import { MyAppCheckboxModule } from 'projects/my-app-ui/src/lib/my-app-checkbox/my-app-checkbox.module'`

[The repository](https://github.com/jasonrichdarmawan/angular-workspace-example/commit/0e55d0c94e3534aad5190f9757be9099723e3a4e)

The code:

view1.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { View1RoutingModule } from './view1-routing.module';
import { View1Component } from './view1.component';
import { NavModule } from 'src/app/app3/nav/nav.module';
import { MyAppButtonModule } from '@@myAppUI';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    View1Component,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    View1RoutingModule,
    NavModule,

    MyAppButtonModule,
  ]
})
export class View1Module { }
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
...
    "paths": {
...
      "@@myAppUI": [
        "dist/my-app-ui"
      ]
    }
...
  }
}
```

projects/my-app-ui/src/public-api.ts

```
/*
 * Public API Surface of my-app-ui
 */

export { MyAppUIModule } from './lib/my-app-ui.module';

export { MyAppCheckboxModule } from './lib/my-app-checkbox/my-app-checkbox.module';
export { MyAppCheckboxComponent } from './lib/my-app-checkbox/my-app-checkbox.component';

export { MyAppButtonModule } from './lib/my-app-button/my-app-button.module';
export { MyAppButtonComponent } from './lib/my-app-button/my-app-button.component';
```

[image]

Comment: you should create multiple entry point to allow treeshaking of your library: https://sandroroth.com/blog/angular-library

Comment: you should check the bundle after minification with the help of tools like source-map-explorer. It seems you are checking not minified code.